# matplotlib button color updates only after moving mouse

Tags: python, button, colors, matplotlib, widget

When I change the color of a button it does not update the color till I move the mouse, which for my application is quite annoying...
Can this update be forced? Maybe by generating a mouse event or something? (feels like a dirty trick...)
This is the (simplified code) I'm using:

```
%pylab
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

fig = plt.figure()
def slCallb(val):
    myButton.color = '{0}'.format(val)
    myButton.canvas.draw()             #only updates after moving the mouse
    fig.canvas.draw()                  #redundant?
axSl = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.02])
mySlider = Slider(axSl, 'slider', 0.0, 1.0, color = '#FF0000')
mySlider.on_changed(slCallb)

axBu = plt.axes([0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.075])
myButton = Button(axBu, 'button')
```

Comment: 75% sure that this is an issue with communication between mpl, the gui tool kit (which tool kit are you using?), and the OS (what OS are you using?).  What I suspect the problem is is that mpl updates it's version of things, but the gui toolkit does not repaint the screen.  Please ask exactly one question per question, open a second question about changing the slider color.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I'm using iPython (Py2.7) notebook on win7

Comment: what does `matplotlib.get_backend()` give?  Are you using the in-line or pop-up graphs?  If you are using the Qt backend, this is probably due to a known issue with the Qt library on windows (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2844)

Comment: This is what Matplotlib.get_backed() gives:
'Qt4Agg'

Comment: Yeah, I bet you are getting bitten by that issue.  Try using a different backend or upgrading to the master-branch version of mpl.I now think I was wrong in pushing back against that patch so much.....

Comment: So you could well be right. 
I'm using a pop up window for the graphics.
Would this be solved if I upgrade to python 3 or any other newer version?
Or is it independent of this?

Comment: I don't think so, there is a work around on the master branch.  See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2559 for code that will monkey-patch matplotlib with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  If you look at Button source code in maptplotlib\Widgets.py, you will see that as long as the mouse is over the button, it will show the hover color.  So if you need your button's color to change while your mouse is still over the button, you will have to disable/mask this behavior.  I am lazy, so I simply created my button with its hover color being the same as when button is clicked.  For example, if my button will be green after the click, create the button as Button(ax, "my button", hovercolor='g').  Then in the on_clicked event handler function, do myButton.color = 'g' and call figure.canvas.draw() to force the change.
I'm sure there are many other more elegant ways to solve this problem.